# python - append item to list always as a sub-list

Tags: python, list, append

What would be the most efficient way to append an item into an existing list as another sub-list. for instance, considering *data['rows']* is a list, the following:

```
 for indx, row in enumerate(my_data):
    data['rows'].append(row)
```

does the job in when row is already a list.

```
> 'Rows': [['150', '01'], ['10', '02'], ['22', '03'], ['33', '4'] ...
```

however if the value in *row* is not a list, this will produce:

```
> 'Rows': ['150', '10', '22', '33', '44', '15']
```

I've a condition that in case a row is not a list it uses `data['Rows'].append(list(row))` but there must be a better way..

Comment: `data['Rows'].append(list())` Will not sub-list an existing list. So you should be find to use that in either scenario.  It does however create a copy.. so be aware of that.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question, something like

> I have a list of elements, these elements may be lists already, they may not be.  If they are lists, I want them appended as such.  If they *aren't* lists, I want them wrapped in a list, and then I want the resulting single-element list appended.

This is something I too have struggled with, and the best I could come up with is something like the following:

```
elems = [1,2,[3,4],5]

data1 = []
for e in elems:
    data1.append(e if isinstance(e, list) else [e,])
print data1

# Or with a lambda function that does the work for you
wrap = lambda x: x if isinstance(x, list) else [x,]

data2 = []
for e in elems:
    data2.append(wrap(e))
print data2
```

Both output:

```
[[1], [2], [3, 4], [5]]
```

Comment: That is great, lambda also do the job! Why is the comma  needed on: ...else [x,]

Comment: @Algina It's not. It's actually only necessary when dealing with tuples that consist of a single element. I'm guessing jedwards used that form out of habit.

Comment: It's not.  It's just habit.  For single-element lists `[x]` is fine.  For single-element *tuples*, you need it: `(x,)`

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly, you could do something like this:

```
data['Rows']=data.get('Rows', []).append(list(row))
```

This will create the list if it isn't present in the dictionary already.

You might consider rephrasing your question to make it more clear. You say "if it's not a list", but it isn't clear what it is then. Since you are working with dicts I assumed it meant that the key is not present.